# Outputstream write only when I close Eclipse Application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, outputstream, processbuilder

Goodmorning guys,

I'm trying to develop an Eclipse Plugin that run an external program with ProcessBulder.

During the exectution, I try to write the output on disk, but the plugin doesn't write anything until I close the execution of Eclipse Application.

```
public void run() 
    {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("NuSMV.exe","-int");
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = pb.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        OutputStream out = process.getOutputStream();
        // Write commands
        PrintWriter commands = new PrintWriter(out);        
        commands.println("reset");
        commands.println("set default_trace_plugin 4");             
        commands.println("read_model -i C:\\temp/ascensore.smv");               
        commands.println("go");
        commands.println("check_ctlspec");
        commands.println("show_traces -o C:\\temp/showtraces.xml");     
        commands.close();
        process.getOutputStream().close();

    }
```

Showtraces.xml is written after the end of eclipse. How Can I have the output before this closing?

Answer (score 0):

First flush the printwriter then close it.

ie

```
commands.flush();
```

Refer.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#flush--

Answer (score 0):

I've already tried to use commands.flush() before call the close() method, but this don't change anything.

Instead, if I write more than one file, as an example file-1.xml, file-2.xml, file-3.xml, the files numer one and two was written before I closing the application and the file number three was written only after closing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it will help but try to change this:

```
commands.close();
process.getOutputStream().close();
```

To this:

```
commands.flush();
commands.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Comment: My assumption is based on that you create a new instance of OutputStream when you call it from process instead of using OutputStream that you have just used in your Writer. Might be wrong though as I cannot try right now.

Answer (score 0):

Use another constructor to have the `autoflush` mode set ([see Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.OutputStream-boolean-)).

```
PrintWriter commands = new PrintWriter(out, true);
```

Changing this allows you to keep your code with minimal change.

Every call to `println`, `printf` and `format` flushes the buffer automatically, fixing your issues.